# Fluent nHibernate many-to-many mapping

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I am trying to create entity with two FK from tables Group and Person.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int p_id { get; set; }
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Person> ppl { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public virtual int g_id { get; set; }
    public virtual string name{ get; set;}
    public virtual IList<Group> groups { get; set; }
}
```

Many-to-many mapping:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.ppl)
    .Table("gp")
    .ParentKeyColumn("g_id")
    .ChildKeyColumn("p_id");

HasManyToMany(x => x.groups)
     .Table("gp")
     .ParentKeyColumn("p_id")
     .ChildKeyColumn("g_id")
     .Inverse();
```

Problem is that both constrains in table gp are referencing on table person.
Show create table command:

```
CREATE TABLE `gp` (
`g_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
KEY `p_id` (`p_id`),
KEY `g_id` (`g_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK4B9E89089BCCDC65` FOREIGN KEY (`g_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`p_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK4B9E8908E34BCD9E` FOREIGN KEY (`p_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`p_id`)
```

Want to:

```
CREATE TABLE `gp` (
`g_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
KEY `p_id` (`p_id`),
KEY `g_id` (`g_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK4B9E89089BCCDC65` FOREIGN KEY (`g_id`) REFERENCES `group` (`g_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK4B9E8908E34BCD9E` FOREIGN KEY (`p_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`p_id`)
```

I tried to delete Inverse() in group mapping and use it in person table but I got following exception: "The relationship has Inverse specified on both sides".
Does anyone knows why are constraints referencing one table?

Answer (score 1):

I have this:

1. I do not have "Inverse".
2. You have (singular)

   ```
   .ParentKeyColumn("p_id")
   .ChildKeyColumn("g_id")
   ```

I have adding to the collection, maybe something to try.

```
    .ParentKeyColumns.Add("p_id")
    .ChildKeyColumns.Add("g_id")

            (and vice versa)
```

Here are my 2 mappings (unaltered from my world, where Employee(s) have ParkingArea(s) and vice versa)............

```
        /* the below is how to do it without a surogatekey on the link table */
        HasManyToMany<ParkingAreaNHEntity>(x => x.MyParkingAreas)
       .Table("EmployeeToParkingAreaLink")
            .ParentKeyColumns.Add("AbcEmployeeUUID", p => p.UniqueKey("Emp_ParkingArea_Unique").Index("IX_ABC123"))
            .ChildKeyColumns.Add("AbcParkingAreaUUID", p => p.UniqueKey("Emp_ParkingArea_Unique"))
            .Cascade.None()
            ;




        /* the below is how to do it without a surogatekey on the link table */
        HasManyToMany<EmployeeNHEntity>(x => x.MyEmployees)
       .Table("EmployeeToParkingAreaLink")
            .ParentKeyColumns.Add("AbcParkingAreaUUID", p => p.UniqueKey("Emp_ParkingArea_Unique").Index("IX_ABC123"))
            .ChildKeyColumns.Add("AbcEmployeeUUID", p => p.UniqueKey("Emp_ParkingArea_Unique"))
            .Cascade.None()
            ;
```

Comment: Please mark an answer as "The Answer" so this does not show up as "Unanswered questions" on the SOF queries.

Answer (score 0):

found solution:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.ppl)
.Table("gp")
.ChildKeyColumns.Add("p_id");

HasManyToMany(x => x.groups)
 .Table("gp")
 .ChildKeyColumns.Add("g_id")
```